# Начинать внутренний each() со следующей итерации

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. У меня есть такой код. Задача поместить Name1 в первый `<div_to_change>` а Name2 во второй.
Я использую цикл в цикле. При таком коде Name2 вписывается в оба `<div_to_change>` потому, что внутренняя итерация каждый раз перезаписывает себя делая две итерации.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как внутренний цикл каждый раз начинать со следующей итерации?

```js
var current = 'Current Name';
var name;
$(".first_each").each(function() {
  $(".second_each").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == current) {
      name = $(this).parent().find(".child").html();
    }
  });
  $(".div_to_change", this).html(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second_each">Current Name</div>
  <div class="child">Name1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second_each">Current Name</div>
  <div class="child">Name2</div>
</div>

<div class="first_each">
  <div class="div_to_change"></div>
</div>
<div class="first_each">
  <div class="div_to_change"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var current = 'Current Name';
$(".second_each").each(function(index, value) {
  if ($(this).text() == current) {
    $('.div_to_change:eq(' + index + ')').html($(this).next('.child').html());
  }
});
```

```css
div.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

div.first_each {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second_each">Current Name</div>
  <div class="child">Name1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second_each">Current Name</div>
  <div class="child">Name2</div>
</div>

<div class="first_each">
  <div class="div_to_change"></div>
</div>
<div class="first_each">
  <div class="div_to_change"></div>
</div>
```

я тут воспользовался [eq](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83), который соответствует по индексу номеру элемента в итерации.

и еще [next](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), который осуществляет поиск элементов, лежащих непосредственно после заданных элементов

и да, у `each` в callback могут передаваться 2 параметра: номер элемента в наборе (нумерация начинается с нуля) и сам элемент в виде объекта DOM. Я воспользовался как раз `index`, чтобы его вставить потом в `eq`

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Хороший способ, я не знал про eq().

Но если добавить еще один .parent в начало в котором "Current Name" будет другим, то "if" перескочит через него и нумерация собьется первый ".div_to_change" будет пустым.

Пробую разные варианты с eq(), но к сожалению проблему не могу решить. Я подумал, может можно добавлять все отфильтрованные 'Current Name' в массив, а потом доставать по очереди для каждого "div_to_change"?

Comment: @r0h если ожидается несооответствие количества `second_each` с `first_each`, то надо решать вообще всё по-другому. возможно банально нужно генерировать динамически шаблон, отталкиваясь от количества найденных данных. В ином же случае всё это через попу логика и через циклы нерешаема. Сейчас добавишь один `.parent`,  с другим "Current Name", завтра у тебя блоков с "Current Name" будет на 5 больше, чем существующих `first_each`, послезавтра наоборот. Что делать в таком случае? Я не знаю какую задачу ты решаешь. Тебе надо было сформулировать именно её, чтобы узнать как лучше её решать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, как у меня получилось:

```js
    current = 'Current Name'
    var multiArray = [];
    $(".first_each").each(function(i){
      $(".second_each").each(function(e){
        if($(this).html() == current) {
          multiArray.push($(this).parent().find(".child").html());
        }
      });
      $(".div_to_change", this).html(multiArray[i]);
    });
```

```css
.div_to_change {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second_each">Bad Name</div>
  <div class="child">Name1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second_each">Current Name</div>
  <div class="child">Name1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second_each">Current Name</div>
  <div class="child">Name2</div>
</div>

<div class="first_each">
  <div class="div_to_change"></div>
</div>
<div class="first_each">
  <div class="div_to_change"></div>
</div>
```

Спасибо stranger in the day за помощь